# Transition animation click only works once

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

Why does my page transition only work once (the animation doesn't run after)?  Could someone tell me how to make this work by changing the function `side(el)`?

This is my JavaScript:

```
function fall(el) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(el);
        elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-in 0s";
        elem.style.left = "0px";

        document.getElementById('product').style.height="0px";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.opacity=0;


        document.getElementById('home').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('product').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('work').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('about').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function rotate(el) {
        var elem =document.getElementById(el);
        elem.style.transition = "height 0.5s linear 0s";
        elem.style.height = "100%";

        document.getElementById('home').style.transition = "left .5s ease-out 0s";
        document.getElementById('home').style.left = "-3500px";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.opacity=0;



        document.getElementById('home').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('product').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('work').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('about').style.visibility="hidden";
        }

function flip(el) {
        var elem =document.getElementById(el);
        elem.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
        elem.style.opacity = 1;

        document.getElementById('product').style.height="0px";
        document.getElementById('home').style.left = "-3500px";


        document.getElementById('home').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('product').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('work').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('about').style.visibility="hidden";}

function cube(el) {
        var elem =document.getElementById(el);
        elem.style.transition = "right 0.5s ease-in-out 0s";
        elem.style.right = "0px";

        document.getElementById('home').style.left = "-3500px";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.opacity=0;
        document.getElementById('product').style.height="0px";

        document.getElementById('home').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('product').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('work').style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById('about').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function side(el) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(el);
        document.getElementById('about').className ="pt-page-ontop pt-page-rotateInNewspaper pt-page";


        document.getElementById('home').style.left = "-3500px";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.opacity=0;
        document.getElementById('product').style.height="0px";

        document.getElementById('home').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('product').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('activity').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('work').style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById('about').style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Comment: have you checked your console for any errors. Or have you used any tools like chrome development tool, which will help you understand what is happening using breakpoints

Comment: Can you post a HTML sample?

Comment: Im not used tool development.
THIS HTML CODE :

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mustika Transition</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animations.css" />
<script src="js/transisipage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

Comment: <input type="image" src="image/home.gif" onclick="fall('home')">
<input type="image" src="image/product.gif" onClick="rotate('product')">
<input type="image" src="image/activity.gif" onClick="flip('activity')">
<input type="image" src="image/work.gif" onClick="cube('work')">
<input type="image" src="image/about.gif" onClick="side('about')">
<div class="pt-perspective">
 <div id="home" class="pt-page">Isi home</div>
 <div id="product" class="pt-page">Isi product</div>
    <div id="activity" class="pt-page">Isi gallery</div>
    <div id="work" class="pt-page">Isi work</div>

Comment: <div id="about" class="pt-page" >Isi about</div>
</div>
<script src="js/pagetransitions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>